# Processor cores over heating

Tags: desktop, overheating

I was at home and everything was working fine.

I packed up my desktop and drove to a friends house being careful to not jolt as I drove. When I got there the cpu cores were over heating.

I had forgotten my power cable so i am borrowing one. As I understand this shouldn’t be an issue but worth noting.

I am using an NZXT water cooler on my processor and it has worked for 8-9 months.

I’ve tried unplugging and replugging everything back in to make sure nothing fell out while I was driving or carrying the computer. I also tried plugging the different components into different parts of the power supply.

I’m not seeing different results.

It seems farfetched that the liquid cooler would break with 30 minutes of driving and using a different cable shouldn’t matter as the box controls the power.

Any ideas or clarifications are appreciated.

Comment: How much are they overheating? Have you removed the CPU portion of the cooler, cleaned the surfaces, applied fresh thermal paste, and reinstalled?

Comment: Idle temperature is 80c on bios screen, it went from working perfectly to not working over a span of 30 minutes with the only significant thing i did was drive with it in my car. I haven’t gone to the lengths of reinstalling the water cooler since it was previously installed 8 months prior and i hadn’t tampered with the hardware in that way. My next step is to find out if the water cooler is working properly, but i’m not too sure how to do that....

Comment: When the action upon the computer in the ensuing period was physical, the issue is likely physical. The car ride most likely jarred the cooling system out of place.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that the liquid cooler was not pressing hard enough up against the processor.

I was able to decipher this because when I pulled the liquid cooler off there was no suction or pull back as well as the thermal paste was all crusty. Crusty thermal paste means that the thermal paste was baking and the heat was not being transferred away.

I purchased a heatsink and attached it. Just to be sure it was attached snuggly I took it off to prove that the heatsink was sticking and when I loaded up the computer it worked.

The liquid cooler was removed and attached 4 times and each time provided no pull back from the thermal paste sticking. I double checked the instructions and I had used the proper screws and stubs to mount the liquid cooler. I don't really understand how this issue can occur. Hopefully someone else can make sense of it.